# How to annotate more than one value in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, annotations

I want to expand existing queryset.

I tried the following:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('article'))
    return qs
```

It works perfectly for one annotation. But how can I add more?

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('article'))
    qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('comment'))
    return qs
```

With above solution results go crazy. When it should show:

- `2` articles
- `2` comments

it shows:

- `4` articles
- `4` comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this

```
Count('article', distinct=True)

def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('article', distinct=True))
    qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('comments', distinct=True))
    return qs
```